# AbstractMethodError when running standalone jar built with SBT and ProGuard

Tags: scala, executable-jar, sbt, proguard

I've written a simple Scala application that I'd like to distribute in the form of a standalone, executable jar to servers without the Scala runtime.  Everything works fine when invoked through `SBT run`, but not `java -jar`.

When I run the jar through java, I get the following unhandled exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: java.util.logging.Handler.publish(Ljava/util/logging/LogRecord;)V
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:458)
    at net.lag.logging.Logger.log(Logger.scala:108)
    at net.lag.logging.Logger.log(Logger.scala:91)
    at net.lag.logging.Logger.info(Logger.scala:121)
    at com.rentawebgeek.sitewiki.SiteWiki$.main(SiteWiki.scala:29)
    at com.rentawebgeek.sitewiki.SiteWiki.main(SiteWiki.scala)
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: java.util.logging.Handler.close()V
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.resetLogger(LogManager.java:682)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.reset(LogManager.java:665)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$Cleaner.run(LogManager.java:223)
```

I'm using Configgy and it's Logger, and, per the javadocs for [AbstractMethodError](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html), thought it might be related to Scala/SBT using a different Java version than what I'm invoking from my shell.  However, `java -version` and `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` (what `/usr/local/bin/scala` uses) both match up as 1.6.0_22.

My ProGuard options are:

```
//program entry point
override def mainClass: Option[String] = Some("com.rentawebgeek.sitewiki.SiteWiki")

//proguard
override def proguardOptions = List(
    "-keepclasseswithmembers public class * { public static void main(java.lang.String[]); }",
    "-dontoptimize",
    "-dontobfuscate",
    "-keep class *",
    proguardKeepLimitedSerializability,
    proguardKeepAllScala,
    "-keep interface scala.ScalaObject"
)

override def proguardInJars = Path.fromFile(scalaLibraryJar) +++ super.proguardInJars
```

How can I resolve this error?  Or find another way to build an executable jar from an SBT project for a Scala-less deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out what call you are making at line 29 in SiteWiki.scala; that is the offending call. You're probably calling a trait/class there with an abstract method. Most probably the method that should implement the abstract method is ripped away by proguard (or there the Scala override doesn't match up (I've seen that happen)).

If the line is long to find the offending call; try to decompose over multiple lines.

Comment: You were right: ProGuard was removing something that mattered.  For now, I was able to solve it by removing my `-keep` options and instead using `-dontshrink`.  I don't care about the size of the jar for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The latest ProGuard releases contain a sample configuration for processing a Scala application plus the Scala runtime:

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#scala

If that doesn't work, the output of -printconfiguration and the console output might help finding the root cause.